# How to apply the where condition on json instead of table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-workbench

I am trying to apply the where clause on json data instead of table and column. I have tried lots of way but didn't get the result as I want.

Below is a query:

```
select 
CustomerName as 'CustomerName',
TRUNCATE(JSON_VALUE(BillData, '$[0].due'), 3) as 'Balance'
from 
(
select
CONCAT(cd.FirstName, ' ',cd.LastName) as 'CustomerName',
sb.billData as 'BillData'
from test.customerData cd
inner join test.customerbills sb on cd.customerCode = sb.customerCode
) as tb
```

BillData is a json.BillData contains data like below:

```
[{
"isPastDue":true,
"isPrinted":true,
"dueDate":"2023-03-28"
},
{
"isPastDue":false,
"isPrinted":true,
"dueDate":"2023-04-22"
},
{
"isPastDue":false,
"isPrinted":false,
"dueDate":"2023-05-06"
}]
```

Now, I want to get the dueDate of that node which isPastDue and isPrinted flag is false.

I have spend lots of time for get the proper data but didn't found it. I found the solution like below but it's not working.

```
(
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(BillData, '$.dueDate') AS item
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(BillData, '$.isPrinted') = 'false'
and JSON_EXTRACT(BillData, '$.isPastDue') = 'false'
) as 't1'
```

Next when I run the query then it's showing null in the result. How can I achieve the result as per expectation?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like "BillData" is an array of objects, while you are trying to access a single object.
Please try this approach:

```
(
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(BillData, '$[*].dueDate') AS item
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(BillData, '$[*].isPrinted') = 'false'
and JSON_EXTRACT(BillData, '$[*].isPastDue') = 'false'
) as 't1'
```

If this is not working, you have to go through the indexes of the array manually.

Comment: with index as well not returning the value. It's showing null with index and without index.

Comment: Maybe at this point it is better from aperformance point of view to get the JSON Arrays and do the actual selection in your code. At last it depends on the number of Arrays you have to retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get the dueDate of that node which isPastDue and isPrinted
> flag is false

You can use `json_table` to convert your array of objects into table as follows :

```
SELECT *
FROM customerData cd
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(
                       cd.billData,
                      '$[*]' 
                       COLUMNS (
                       isPastDue tinyint PATH '$.isPastDue',
                       isPrinted tinyint PATH '$.isPrinted',
                       dueDate DATE PATH '$.dueDate'
                      ) ) j
```

So your query can be something like this :

```
SELECT CONCAT(cd.FirstName, ' ',cd.LastName) as 'CustomerName', j.*
FROM customerData cd
inner join customerbills sb on cd.customerCode = sb.customerCode
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(
                       cd.billData,
                      '$[*]' 
                       COLUMNS (
                       isPastDue tinyint PATH '$.isPastDue',
                       isPrinted tinyint PATH '$.isPrinted',
                       dueDate DATE PATH '$.dueDate'
                      ) ) j
where isPastDue = 0 and isPrinted = 0
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/XqugUI-b)

Comment: why we have used the mytable there? we are already using the json data from the sub query so why should we define and fetch the json again or why should we define table name again?

Comment: Its used to illustrate how to extract elements from json array